# How can an IpAddr be converted to an IPv4Addr?

Tags: rust

In Rust, it is easy to create an `IpAddr` from an `IpV4Addr`:

```
let ipv4 = IpV4Addr::new(127,0,0,1);
let ip = IpAddr::V4(ipv4);
```

But it seems that there is no way back:

```
if ip.is_ipv4() {
    let ipv4: IpV4Addr = .....?
}
```

The reason is that I need to access the octets of the IPv4 address at some point (via `IPv4::octets`) to transfer them over the network. However, I'd like to use the more generic `IpAddr` representation in other parts of the application, since I want to implement IPv6 in the future, therefore making the network code not IPv4-specific.

Comment: I recommend reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/) to become familiar with basic concepts in Rust, such as [enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-00-enums.html).

Comment: I did read it (+ the 1st edition), but I have trouble applying theoretical information like this to real-world problems; this is just a personal weakness of me (I usually need a practical example to "get" something). If you feel that questions like this are not appropriate for SO, I will refrain from posting them in the future.

Comment: I do not think such questions are *inappropriate*, just that I feel that they've already been answered by the book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) is an abstraction for IP addresses. It is an enum which holds either an `Ipv4Addr` or `Ipv6Addr` and some methods to provide abstract access to either.

Rust won't let you cast an `IpAddr` to an `Ipv4Addr` because what if it's actually an `Ipv6Addr`? You have to handle that case as well. You convince Rust that you've handled all possibilities with `match`.

```
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, Ipv6Addr};

fn main() {
    let ips = [
        IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)),
        IpAddr::V6(Ipv6Addr::new(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)),
    ];

    for ip in ips.iter() {
        match *ip {
            IpAddr::V4(ip4) => println!("ipv4: {}, octets: {:?}", ip4, ip4.octets()),
            IpAddr::V6(ip6) => println!("ipv6: {}, segments: {:?}", ip6, ip6.segments()),
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need for a default case because the Rust type checker knows there is no other possibility. `ips` is an array of `IpAddr` and that contains only two possibilities, V4 or V6. In fact, Rust will warn if you put one there so should `IpAddr` change in the future you will be made aware with a compile error.

Answer (score 5):

[`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) is an enum, so you can use pattern matching:

```
if let IpAddr::V4(ipv4) = ip {
    // here ipv4 is of type IpV4Addr
}

// or, if you need to handle IPv6 as well

match ip {
    IpAddr::V4(ipv4) => { /* handle IPv4 */ }
    IpAddr::V6(ipv6) => { /* handle IPv6 */ }
}
```

Also, `IpAddr` is `Copy`, so you don't even need to worry about consuming its original value (the `ip` variable), it will just be implicitly copied for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hope you don't mind that I accepted Schwern's answer (just because it is a bit more elaborate).